# How can I compare two integers in one array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner in Java. I have an array of integers: I want to count how many integers in this array are bigger than the integer directly following them. So first I want to look at the integer at index 0, and check if it's bigger than the integer at index 1. Then I look at the integer at index 1, and check if it's bigger than the integer at index 2. And so forth.

So far, here's what I've got:

```
    int[] t = {1,5,6,4,3,10}; // create an array of integers
    int sum = 0; //initialize sum at 0

    for (int i=0; i<t.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j<t.length; j++){
            if (t[i]>t[j]){                  //if i is bigger than j
                sum += 1;                   //add 1 to sum
                System.out.println(t[i]);
            }
    }

    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

For this array, sum should be 2 : 6 is bigger than 4, and 4 is bigger than 3. Problem is, the code returns 5. I've tried printing t[i] in the if loop to understand what's going on: it prints 5,5,6,6,4. I don't get why 5 would be bigger than 6 in this context. It also looks like it's looping more than one time, so I'm obviously doing something wrong with the iteration. But I really can't see where the problem is. So, my question is: what have done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are expecting it to check just the next element, but you are checking next element to the end

This is what is happening with your current code

```
1,5,6,4,3,10

5 > 4
5 > 3
6 > 4
6 > 3
4 > 3
```

and so count   =  5

remove inner loop and change condition to

```
if (t[i] < t[i+1]){
    sum += 1;
}
```

Comment: So the double for loop checks the current element against every following element... I understand what happened now, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

This is much easier to do in a single for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<t.length-1; i++){
    if (t[i]>t[i+1]){
        sum +=1;
        System.out.println(t[i]);
    }
}
```

Currently, what you're doing is for each value `i` you're comparing it to all the values after it, not just the next value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j = i+1; j<t.length; j++){
```

You don't want this second `for` loop.  You just want `j = i + 1`, and nothing else.  What you want is more like

```
for (int i=0; i<t.length-1; i++) {
        if (t[i]>t[i + 1]){                  //if i is bigger than j
            sum += 1;                   //add 1 to sum
            System.out.println(t[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second loop is not required. Just keep increasing i by 1 and compare ith and (i+1)th element. This should be like:-

```
for (int i=0; i<t.length-1; i++) {
    if (t[i]>t[i+1]){                  //if i is bigger than i+1
            sum += 1;                   //add 1 to sum
        }
}
```